# click a button programmatically in a website

Tags: javascript, java, c#, php, button

Well i want to build a bot thats clicks a button after amount of time like every 5 hours,
how can i do that?
i prefer in PHP , but if there any other language that you know , i know also C#,Java,JS.. 
any suggestions to start, i just never did it before and i want to do learn how to do it very much, i have been searching, didn't find nothing.
Thank a lot!.
I already tried in chrome what the button send , and it send javascripts:void(0) something like and location.href = /Blah/blaahh.php.

Comment: what does the button do? if it sends a request, instead of clicking the button you actually want to mimic the request, the simplest way to do that in php is with CURL.  The button is likely irrelevant, think of it simply as the trigger for that request.

Answer (score 1):

So basically your question is `programmatically click a button` and trigger it in a certain `time interval`. So what came up to my mind was the solution below:

```
<script>
  setInterval(function(){ 
    $('#button').trigger('click');
  }, 3000);
</sctipt>
```

The code above will `trigger` and the button will be triggered as clicked and it will take place for every amount of time. After the button is being clicked, try to add some function to handle the event after the button is technically being clicked.

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

You must use `setTimeout` on every `n < 10` seconds to prevent the browser from sleeping, `setInterval` with hours not a good idea.

In my opinion, The best two ways to implement something like that is:

1. Node.js
2. setTimeout every 10 seconds and loop on the same function, and each time check if the last click was 5 hours ago.

## Javascript Example `setTimeout`:

```js
var CLICK_EVERY_TIME = 10 * 1000; // i choosed to click every 10 sec
var clickCount = 0;
var lastClick = 0;
var loops = 0;
$(window).ready(function(){
 
  // on page load start you auto clicker
  runner();
});

function performClick(){
  clickCount++;
  $('#clickCount').html("clicks: "+clickCount);
  
  // save last click time
  lastClick = new Date().getTime();
}

function runner(){
  loops++;
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  if(currentTime - Number(lastClick) > CLICK_EVERY_TIME){
    performClick();
  }
  $('#loops').html("runner: "+loops+" loops");
  setTimeout(runner, 1000); // every 1 seconds 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clickCount">clicks: 0</div>
<div id="loops">runner: 0 loops</div>
```

## Node.js:

You have to use [**jsdom**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) to simulate a browser, and perform your clicks.
**Note:** In Node.js you can use `setInterval` with hours as mush as you want, because the Node.js on standalone process.